# Mobile app uses a lot of cache memory

Tags: android, caching, memory, memory-leaks

I have a problem. I created the android app, when I start the app I see 48,09 MB cache memory. My app uses different libraries, has a lot of classes. I  can't find a reason why the app uses so many cache memory? How do I find the problem?

**Interesting thing**: When I start an empty app, this app uses approximately 4Mb cache memory , I think it's too much.

Comment: Do you use some Bitmap ? Cause I know this use a lot of memory

Comment: No, I use  only 2 vector  pictures, from android vector asset. It's strange, but when I start the empty app in another phone the cache memory equals 0!  I use two phone

Comment: 1) Samsung Galaxy j1 mini android 5.0 (this telephone has a strange big cache memory) and 2) Samsung GT-I8262 Android 4.2 (in this phone I can't start my app because I use some libraries which work only with android 5.0-6,0, but the empty app memory cache equals 0 in thid phone)