# A lot of SharedPreferences errors

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When I start my app in Strict Mode I have a lot of the same errors. Emulator shows me  "Storage space runnning out"

**Error:**

```
E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:89)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.createFileOutputStream(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:544)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:592)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:51)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:512)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:533)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:51)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:455)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzUo(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/SharedPreferencesImpl: writeToFile: Got exception:
java.io.IOException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:502)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flushBytes(FastXmlSerializer.java:232)
at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flush(FastXmlSerializer.java:253)
at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.endDocument(FastXmlSerializer.java:198)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:188)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:597)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:51)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:512)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:533)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:51)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:455)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzUo(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)
at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:258)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:497)
```

My **Shared Preference class** is:

```
public class SharedHelper {

public static boolean setProductFilePath(String path) {
    return getAppPreference().edit()
            .putString(Constants.PATH_NAME, path)
            .commit();
}

public static String getProductFilePath() {
    return getAppPreference().getString(Constants.PATH_NAME, "");
}

public static boolean setClientFilePath(String path) {
    return getAppPreference().edit()
            .putString(Constants.PATH_CLIENT_FILE, path)
            .commit();
}

public static String getClientFilePath() {
    return getAppPreference().getString(Constants.PATH_CLIENT_FILE, "");
}

public static boolean setEmail(String path) {
    return getAppPreference().edit()
            .putString(Constants.EMAIL, path)
            .commit();
}

public static String getEmail() {
    return getAppPreference().getString(Constants.EMAIL, "");
}

public static boolean setQuantityColumns(String path) {
    return getAppPreference().edit()
            .putString(Constants.QUANTITY_OF_COLUMNS, path)
            .commit();
}

public static String getQuantityColumns() {
    return getAppPreference().getString(Constants.QUANTITY_OF_COLUMNS, "");
}

public static int getListState() {
    return getAppPreference().getInt(Constants.LIST_STATE, 0);
}

public static boolean setListState(int listState) {
    return getAppPreference().edit()
            .putInt(Constants.LIST_STATE, listState)
            .commit();
}


public static SharedPreferences getAppPreference() {
    return App.newInstance().getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_PREFERENCE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Why I have too many errors? (approximately 20 the same errors)

Comment: did you put the desired permission? seems to me like you forgot to add some.

Comment: Yes, I have all necessary permission:                                                     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: you are getting error because there is not enough space in your device to write a file. check following so thread and select solution that might be good for your situation

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Caused+by%3A+android.system.ErrnoException%3A+write+failed%3A+ENOSPC+(No+space+left+on+device)&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=S_hfV7XwGrPR8AeY8YrgCg

Comment: are you using emulator or real device to test your code?

Comment: This  problem has some different aspects. This error I  have when I use emulator API 22, but when I  use a real device I have another problem with cache memory - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792548/mobile-app-uses-a-lot-of-cache-memory

Comment: I read a lot of information about the error but I can't find a solution

Comment: So for this you can try increasing memory of the emulator and run your code again

Comment: Yes, but in AVD manager I see size on disk 1 GB I think it's enough or I need increasing memory in another place?

Comment: there will be internal storage option, you can try increasing over there

Comment: how to increase emulator internal storage? But  I  have the problem with large cache memory on a real device at all!

Comment: see this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/react-native-android-studio-avd-windows.png

Comment: Thank's for the image. I'll try to  increase RAM,HEAP and internal storage. What size  of  this memories  is enough for app? RAM - 2GB, HEAP - 1GB, Internal storage - 1GB? or is this so large? The device gets this memory from computer RAM  memory?

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper class and avoid the complexity. Here is one that i wrote - [Android-SharedPreferences-Helper](https://github.com/viralypatel/Android-SharedPreferences-Helper)

> Simplifies usage of the default Android SharedPreferences Class. The
>   developer can do in a few lines of code which otherwise would have
>   required several. Simple to understand as compared to the default
>   class and easy to use.